# gtsummary table - ordinal logistic regression and survey data

Tags: gtsummary

I have the following code, which is an attempt to get a table of univariate regression results for weighted survey data using ordinal logistic regression. I can't use the polr function since that doesn't seem to accomodate survey designs. Yet, this code, which uses the clm function, is yielding an error. What am I missing here?

```
table <- 
    svydesign(ids = ~1,data = df,weights = ~pweight) |>
    tbl_uvregression(
      method = clm,
      y = outcome,
      method.args = list(link=logit),
      include = c(RRACE, RHISPANIC,age, agecat,
                  REGION, Metro,
                  INCOME, Educ),
      exponentiate = TRUE)
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtrzB.png)